# wsdl has unresolved urls. Service proxy returns null

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I am trying to connect to an external webservice and have no control over it. 
The wsdl has a few unresolved urls. Neither Soap UI not svcutil were able to make any use out of it. 
So I browsed to this wsdl and did a 'Save As' to a xml document. Then I went and manually changed it these few to the correct one.

For eg: 
https://b2borexatest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0*soa_d48cf4e0-5e7b-43ad-b430-727180d48841/RouteEDITransactions_ep?WSDL. T
This was the original webservice Wsdl given. and then they changed it to 
https://orserviceb2btest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0/CORERule220.wsdl

I am able to browse to the second url but it still contains some traces of the old one 'b2b....'
So I went and manually changed these traces to reflect to the correct one. 
By doing so, I was able to create a proxy using svcutil.

Question: Could this be the possible reason for getting a webservice proxy returns null
SOAP UI request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:cor="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
      <cor:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest>
         <PayloadType>123</PayloadType>
         <ProcessingMode>XXX</ProcessingMode>
         <PayloadID>72</PayloadID>
         <TimeStamp>2013-07-13:T23:30:29:45</TimeStamp>
         <SenderID>MID</SenderID>
         <ReceiverID>OID</ReceiverID>
         <CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</CORERuleVersion>
         <Payload>MY Input string</Payload>
      </cor:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>


This is the working SOAP UI response
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<env:Body>
      <COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse xmlns:cor="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
         <cor:PayloadType>XXX</cor:PayloadType>
         <cor:ProcessingMode>23</cor:ProcessingMode>
         <cor:PayloadID>372</cor:PayloadID>
         <cor:TimeStamp>2013-08-04T23:38:32.083-05:00</cor:TimeStamp>
         <cor:SenderID>OID</cor:SenderID>
         <cor:ReceiverID>RID</cor:ReceiverID>
         <cor:CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</cor:CORERuleVersion>
         <cor:Payload>Response String</cor:Payload>
         <cor:ErrorCode>Success</cor:ErrorCode>
         <cor:ErrorMessage></cor:ErrorMessage>
      </COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse>
   </env:Body>
```

I don't see any conflictions in the request/response
These are some relevant pieces of the wsdl

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:CORE="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:CORE-XSD="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="CORE" targetNamespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/">
       <wsdl:types>
          <xsd:schema xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/">
             <xsd:import namespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" schemaLocation="xsd/CORERule2.2.0.xsd"></xsd:import>
          </xsd:schema>
       </wsdl:types>
       <wsdl:message name="RealTimeRequestMessage">
          <wsdl:part name="body" element="CORE-XSD:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest"></wsdl:part>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="RealTimeResponseMessage">
          <wsdl:part name="body" element="CORE-XSD:COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse"></wsdl:part>
       </wsdl:message>



 <wsdl:portType name="CORETransactions">
      <wsdl:operation name="RealTimeTransaction">
         <wsdl:input message="CORE:RealTimeRequestMessage"></wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output message="CORE:RealTimeResponseMessage"></wsdl:output>
 </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>

 <wsdl:binding name="CoreSoapBinding" type="CORE:CORETransactions">
      <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"></soap12:binding>
      <wsdl:operation name="RealTimeTransaction">
         <soap12:operation soapAction="RealTimeTransaction" style="document"></soap12:operation>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"></soap12:body>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"></soap12:body>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
```

I don't see where the proxy class could loose it although Fiddler captures the correct response.

This is a piece of where I invoke the service method using proxy client class

var ORrealTimeTrans = new COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest()
        {
            PayloadType = "blabla",
            ProcessingMode = bla,
            PayloadID = bla,
            CORERuleVersion = bla,
            SenderID = sid,
            ReceiverID = rid,
            TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:22Z"),
            Payload = input
        };

```
    _ORclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserID;
    _ORclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;

    var resp = _ORclient.RealTimeTransaction(ORrealTimeTrans);
```

THis one _ORclient.RealTimeTransaction(ORrealTimeTrans) comes out null.

Could it be possible that I've changed some occurences of b2b to orservice and this proxy returns null?
Please suggest

Comment: take a look at this...single WSDL could fix it. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2011/09/17/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-a-single-wsdl-file.aspx

Comment: @Aron: Can I use this even I have no control over the external service

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the external service's WSDL is what we technically call, BROKEN. If the external service is running on a box with .net 4.5 installed you can automagically use this. However, you either need to ask the vender to fix their config, or hand fix the WSDL each time you build.

Comment: So, to handle this namespace issue, I am using stringbuilder to build the soap string and then doing a Http post. This helps me to capture the response using a HttpWebresponse object. This is not the best way to do it because WCF automatically does all this work.